# Is it possible to specify, in Puppet, to use an rpm for a different OS than the host machine's OS?

Tags: package, puppet, rpm, yum

I've got a machine running an unsupported OS (rhel6.3). It no longer has access to current repos, and cannot be updated for budget reasons.

It needs to have tzdata updated, but the only version it has access to is from 2014.

tzdata is a noarch package - it's just a bunch of binary files - so it doesn't matter if I grab it from another repo, say, our local yum repo which has the latest tzdata packages for other OSs, like centos7.

I know I can simply download and put the latest tzdata rpm locally on the rhel machine, but I'd like this process to be automated - as in, Puppet checks that tzdata is the latest version - and not have to manually go put it in place whenever the tzdata is updated.

Is it possible for Puppet to specify, use this repo, but use the rpm specified for another OS?

Comment: What's stopping you from adding your local repo in the repositories that this rhel6.3 can use? If you still don't want to permanently add it, yum is allowed to use a temporary config file pointing to your local repo. Then you can proceed with update tzdata.

Comment: Well, because we don't want anything else to update (it's a production machine). Just tzdata. And my goal here is for it to always be up-to-date automatically (ensure => latest).

Comment: And `yum update tzdata` will only update `tzdata`.

Comment: But wouldn't "yum update <anything else>" potentially use the repo I added?

Comment: Where is `yum update <anything else>` coming from? You said you are not updating anything. Is there any process that would attempt to update anything that just silently fail now because it has no access to any repo? You should mention it in your post.

Comment: Sorry, I meant this - I think everything on the machine is up to date with the current (out of date) repo. It is managed by puppet. They don't want anything to change, except they now want accurate time zone info for a new reporting feature. I'm just afraid that if I add a new repo, things will start updating themselves. I know I can go back and retrofit and specify versions instead of 'latest' for everything, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way - for instance, just saying 'use this OS's repo for this package.'

Comment: It's doable. Create a new recipe. This new recipe will be a yum recipe that only updates tzdata. In the recipe, tell puppet that the repo is elsewhere, not the repo in another recipe that updates everything else.

Comment: @alvits, the question is tagged [puppet], but what you're describing does not sound like a Puppet solution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - you are absolutely right. My bad, I was thinking of chef.

Answer (score 0):

> tzdata is a noarch package - it's just a bunch of binary files - so it doesn't matter if I grab it from another repo, say, our local yum repo which has the latest tzdata packages for other OSs, like centos7.

Being a noarch package has no such implication.  "Noarch" packages are independent of *machine architecture*, but not necessarily of OS version.  For example, many Python packages are noarch, but the Python2 in EL6 is version 2.6, whereas the Python2 in EL7 is version 2.7.  Noarch Python packages for EL7 do not work properly on EL6 if they rely on any of the features introduced in Python 2.7.  If they are well packaged then such packages won't even install on EL6.

I suspect you're ok with `tzdata` in particular, but there is always a possibility that there has been a change or addition to the format of the packaged files that renders them unusable on older OS versions.  You should be pretty safe, however, if you go with the CentOS 6.7 package for your EL6.3 system, rather than any EL7 package.

> Is it possible for Puppet to specify, use this repo, but use the rpm specified for another OS?

Packages in the same Yum repo are not distinguished by OS or OS version.  Where and to the extent that different OS flavors or versions must be served different package collections, it is done by giving them altogether different repos.  So no, there is no way to instruct Puppet specifically as you describe, because there is no way to instruct `yum` that way.

On the other hand, if you have a local repo that is enabled on the target machine, then you can indeed drop a package built for some other RPM-based distro [version] into that repo.  Clients will see it, and will (attempt to) use it where appropriate based on its name and epoch-version-release codes.  You don't need to do anything special to make that happen.

On the third hand, you could also consider getting the source RPM for the version of tzdata you want, building the binary RPM from it on your EL6.3 machine, and dropping *that* in your local repo.  You can get all manner of source (and binary) RPMs for Fedora and RHEL from [Koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/).

Comment: I like your solution. There is a missing step that you may have overlooked. The new `tzdata` will have a different version and checksum than recorded in metadata. Metadata can be recreated or updated by running `createrepo`.

Comment: @alvits, you are correct that after the RPM file is added to the repository directory, `createrepo` must be run to add its metadata to the repository's store.  I glossed over those details on the assumption that someone already running a local repository, as the OP does, would be familiar with them.  On the other hand, however, she had odd ideas about repos, so maybe it is better to explain the details, as you have now done.